# The Mysterious Stranger and the Shark

Tags: logical-deduction, story

I have just experienced a stranger, who doesn't look at all like a fishing man,   putting a shark in a bag happily.
Why would anyone put a shark in a bag?
Has it got anything to do with the bag or the shark?

Comment: I voted to close this as too broad because there's honestly just not enough information for this to even be a puzzle. I'm curious as to the answer, though, so I encourage you to come back and add a bit more clarification - if you do, I'll be happy to vote to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you just witnessed someone purchase a shark figurine?  The clerk put the figurine in a bag and the person was happy about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna state the obvious answer to get that out of the way:

> He is a fisherman and just caught a shark and is putting it into a bag of ice to preserve it.  Being from Florida, this kind of occurrence would not be unusual (though a cooler of ice would be more likely).